# operating LED Wiz in Linux

Tags: linux, usb

I have a hardware system that uses the LED Wiz from GroovyGameGear.com to control LED's on the front of a system running Windows Embedded.  GroovyGameGear provides a dll (SimpleLEDWiz.dll) that I run from python (cdll from ctypes) to control the LED controller and this works great.

Here's the issue: We are swapping Windows Embedded for Ubuntu 12.04 and I'll (obviously) no longer be able to use the provided dll to control the LED controller (yes I've tried wine).  The developers have sent me some specifications for the data transfers needed that seem simple, but I'm pretty lost at getting this working.  I can see the device when connected in /dev/bus/usb but beyond that I'm unsure what to do.  I'd love to keep this in Python if possible.  This is the information sent to me from the LED Wiz team:

"""Here's what you need to know on the LED-Wiz end;

Developer ID: FAFA
Device numbers : F0 through FF

The format of the reports are very simple:  There are always 8 bytes sent at any one given time and two types of transfers the hardware is expecting.

The first is what we call a "state dump."  This sets the states of the
outputs and is as follows:

Byte 0 = 64   This is a flag used to tell the unit that this data package is a state dump.  It will always be 64

Byte 1 - Byte 5 =  Refer to the KWZ-SBA command.

Byte 6 and Byte 7 = 0  These are always 0 and are "padding"

The "state dump" will also allow recovery from any problems experienced with the "profile dump", as it resets all data counters within the LED-Wiz.  It's a good idea to use a state dump once in a while just to make sure everything is synched.  It shouldn't be necessary since USB communication is well
error-checked, but it's good practice.

The other is the "profile dump."  This one expects 32 bytes of data in four 8 byte chunks.  Think of each chunk as though it is a quarter of the data in the KWZ-PBA command."""

Any help will be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have been working on this as well. The device is an HID device and thus communicates using reports. These are transferred over the control channel. Once I figured this out it was quite simple: if you get pyusb and follow their tutorial (https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst) , the way to get this to work is to issue a control transfer once the device is found:

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import sys
#input is a 5 byte list
def  LWZ_SBA (input):
   #find device
   dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0xfafa, idProduct=0x00f0)
   if dev is None:
      raise ValueError('LedWiz device not found')

   #claim device
   if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(0) is True:
      dev.detach_kernel_driver(0)
   usb.util.claim_interface(dev,0)

   #activate device
   if not dev.get_active_configuration():
      dev.set_configuration(1)

   msg = [64]+input+[0,0]

   #send message to device
   dev.ctrl_transfer(0x21, 0x09, 0x0200, 0, msg)

   #bmRequesttype - 0x21 - HID
   #bmrequest - 0x09 - SET_REPORT
   #wValue - Report Type and Rport ID - 0x02 0x00
   #wIndex - Interface - 0
   #msg - list of values

   #release device
   usb.util.release_interface(dev,0)

#use like this to turn all lights on
LWZ_SBA([255,255,255,255,4])
```

I haven't done PBA yet, but i assume you just issue the same command four times in a row (this time all 8 bytes, and since none of the allowed values is 64, it knows you're setting PBA and not SBA!